# manually render an item in orchard connected using the science project sockets and connectors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

In my project I have overridden the display at the widget level in order to precisely control the markup being produced. The problem I have now is that I can't work out how to render items which are connected using Socket -> Connector -> Socket (in order to achieve a 1-many relationship of items)

http://scienceproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Mechanics

If I insert the default Widget rendering line

```
@Display(Model.Content)
```

I can see using the shape tracer that items of the Sockets are being rendered using the following View

```
~/Modules/Downplay.Mechanics/Views/Socket.cshtml
```

What I want to be able to do is do this manually. I have worked out that

```
Model.Content.ContentItem.MyType.ContentItem.Parts[8]
```

is of type `Downplay.Mechanics.Models.SocketsPart` but `Connectors` is null and I can't see any other reference to Sockets. Can anyone tell me how I would access the connected sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that the model included a list of items, if these were iterated through, the items i needed were the items with a ConnectorType set.

```
<ul class="assets">
    @{
        foreach (var item in Model.Content.Content.Items) {
            if (item.ConnectorType != null)
                {
                @Display.Socket(Content: item)
        }
                }
        }
    </ul>
```